# Why do the standard library use static_cast to unsigned char for char equality comparison?

Tags: c++, char, comparison

From [a reference documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/char_traits/cmp) of `std::char_traits<>::eq()` for characters type equality comparison, I read the following:

> 1. Compares `a` and `b` for equality, behaves identically to
>
> - `static_cast<unsigned char>(a) == static_cast<unsigned char>(b)`, if char_type is char,
> - `a == b` otherwise.

I'm wondering what is the rationale behind these `static_cast`s to `unsigned char` if the type is `char` ?

I'm struggling to understand why do we care of the signedness of `char` (whether or not it is `signed` on the current platform) if we only want to compare them for equality.

Comment: It's just for consistency, all comparisons are done "as if" the values are unsigned. https://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/issue467

Comment: @RichardCritten Oh, indeed, the explanation was just under my eyes...

Answer (score 1):

From the [same reference page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/char_traits/cmp), the answer is given in the ***"Defect reports"*** section (see below).

---

The following behavior-changing defect reports were applied retroactively to previously published C++ standards.

| DR | Applied to | Behavior as published | Correct behavior |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| LWG 467 | C++98 | for std::char_traits<char>, the semantics of eq() and lt() are the same as the built-in `==` and `<` on char respectively[1] | changed to built-in `==` and `<` on unsigned char |

↑ Most implementations call std::memcmp() for efficiency, which interprets the data as arrays of unsigned char. If char is signed on such implementations, std::char_traits<char> fails to satisfy the requirements of *CharTraits*.